# Reading timestamps when importing data in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, import, format, timestamp

I am trying to read a text file into an Oracle database using the Data Import Wizard in SQL Developer.

I am stuck on step 5 because I cannot get the Verify parameters before import to succeed on my `timestamp` fields.

Going back to step 4, I have tried changing the Data type of my `timestamp` fields to `Timestamp`, `Timestamp with time zone`, and `Timestamp with local time zone`. In desperation, I even tried `Date`. Nothing worked.

I then noticed the Format field that shows up when you select any of the `Timestamp...` or `Date` types for the "Data Type" field. So, I tried specifying the format for my data, an example of which follows: `01/03/2008 06:25:00 AM -0500`.

Not sure what the proper codes are for the format and finding no documentation online, offline, or in my head, I tried all of the following formats to no avail: `MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:SS AM +0000`; `MM/DD/YYYY HH:mi:SS AM +0000`; `MM/DD/YYYY HH12:mm:SS AM +0000`; `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM +0000`.

In further desperation, I have tried many, many combinations of the various encodings for each of the sub-elements of the timestamp: `MM` and `mm` for month, `DD` and `dd` for day, `YYYY` and `yyyy` for year, `HH` and `hh` and `HH12` for hour, `mm` and `mi` for minute, `SS` and `ss` for second, and lots of crazy stuff for the `AM/PM` and time zone fields. Nothing has worked.

So, stackoverflow patrons, I ask for your help. I have tried searching for a solution to this problem and I have tried lots of different solutions on my own. I have done my best, but my best hasn't been good enough on this problem. Help me Obi Wan; you're my only hope.

Comment: Ah, Nice formatting. Please use available tools to format your question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the date/time format:

```
MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM TZHTZM
```

And this is the [date format documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm#BABEFHFG).

And you'll need to selet a data type with timezone.