# Unable to read time stamp from Excel in SQL Developer import wizard

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to import the Excel data into my Oracle database through SQL Developer. I have time stamp column in my Excel sheet. While importing into SQL Developer time stamp is reading completely, only date part is reading but not time part. Because of this I am getting error like

> input value not long enough for the date format

My Excel date format is: fmMM/fmDD/yyyy  fmHH:MI:SS AM

I have changed the preferences in SQL developers to the same format. Still no clue. Please help me to get time stamp.

Excel data screen shot:

[image: Excel data]

SQL Devloper preview:

[image: SQL developer preview.]

Comment: Check this URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938050/reading-timestamps-when-importing-data-in-sql-developer

Comment: @Paresh, Changed the date format, but same error.

Comment: Check the date format value in the database. You check the NLS_DATE_FORMAT and check if it is in 12hr or 24hr format.

Comment: NLS_DATE_FORMAT is 12hr format.

Answer (score 1):

Your format for the date column should be:

MM/DD/RR  HH12.MI AM

When you get it right, the SQL Developer wizard will remove the warning mark and it will look something like this:

[image]

And after the wizard finishes..

[image]

I didn't feel like manually typing in your entire screenshot's worth of data, so I just used these 2 rows as a sample:

```
report process id,status,date posted
IM-022553,Closed,6/14/13 10:20 PM
IM-022553,Open,6/7/13 1:25 AM
```